# ArcGIS JS not performing GeometryService cut method

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-js-api

I have an app where users can draw a shape on the map to indicate potential land use, and they can also draw a shape to indicate a 'no change' zone, where we want to indicate no development plans.

Basically, they can create a shape to indicate an industrial zone, and then they could draw an overlapping shape to basically cut out that industrial zone, and designate that zone as a no-development zone.

Here's my code:

```
function cutOutNoChangeZone () {
    var geometries = land_use_planning.graphics,
        geometries_to_be_cut,
        geoService = new esri.tasks.GeometryService("http://gis.website.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Geometry/GeometryServer");

    for (var i = 0, len = geometries.length; i < len; i++) {
        var geometry = geometries[i];
        if (geometry.planning_type === 'no_change') {
            // cut ALL polygons that are under the no change zone
            geometries_to_be_cut = geometries.slice(0, i);
            // NEXT LINE THROWS ERROR
            geoService.cut(geometries_to_be_cut, geometry);
        }
    }
}
```

It throws an error in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'toJson' of undefined

It's coming from the minified ArcGIS 3.9 `init.js` file on the js.arcgis.com server.  I have already debugged the for loop to check that the geometries are valid geometries, with `toJson` methods.  I was trying to follow the example on this esri forum, which shows a similar function: https://geonet.esri.com/thread/63777.

Also note that I am testing this on only two shapes: one industrial and one "no-change" that overlaps.  `geometries_to_be_cut` is an array of the single geometry, and `geometry` is the "no-change" geometry.

It seems like this should be a simple function.  I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, and thought someone might have some insight on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Stepping into the code](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging), we see that the cut method calls `toJson()` on a few different objects:

```
cut: function(a, c, f, g) {
    var e = a[0].spatialReference, p = l.map(a, function(a) {
        return a.toJson()
    });
    a = k.mixin({}, this._url.query, {f: "json",sr: n.toJson(e.toJson()),target: n.toJson({geometryType: u.getJsonType(a[0]),geometries: p}),cutter: n.toJson(c.toJson())});
    var m = this._cutHandler, s = this._errorHandler, B = new h(b._dfdCanceller);
    B._pendingDfd = d({url: this._url.path + "/cut",content: a,callbackParamName: "callback",
        load: function(a, b) {
            m(a, b, e, f, g, B)
        },error: function(a) {
            s(a, g, B)
        }});
    return B
}
```

This method calls `toJson()` on the cutting geometry and on the spatial reference of the first geometry in the list. I suspect that you somehow have a geometry with an undefined `spatialReference` property. Can you check for that please?

Another possible issue is that [according to the documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#cut), the cutting geometry must be a polyline, not a polygon. You didn't specify which one you used, but since you said "draw a shape," maybe the cutting geometry is a polygon. I can't tell yet, because that issue would manifest itself only after the service gets called and returns an error, and because of your `toJson()` error, you're not yet calling the service.

Finally, I'm not sure that the `cut` method does what you need. If you get it working, `cut` will split the input polygons by the cutting polyline, returning the new split polygons. From your description, it sounds like either `difference` or `intersect` would be closer to what you need. But maybe I misunderstood what you wanted to do.

Sorry for the laundry list but hopefully something here is useful. :-)

Comment: I was passing an array of graphics.  Needed to loop over and create an array of `graphics[i].geometry`.  I thought cut would cut out the intersection, but apparently it doesn't.  How can I use intersect to cut out the intersection?  Do you know off hand?  I'm investigating currently.  Thanks! :)

Comment: I'm glad you figured out that it was Graphic vs. Geometry. Use [GeometryService.difference()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#difference) to cut out the intersection.

Comment: So, I could delete the overlapping geometries, and replace them with the differences?  I might need a better solution for my specific case, but thanks for the solution to this problem! :)